How difficult is it for East Jerusalem Arabs to gain Israeli citizenship, and why have most not done so?
In theory Israel offered citizenship to everyone living in the parts of Jerusalem it annexed, but the majority remain stateless. Why? Is it for ideological reasons or practical ones?

The small number claiming citizenship is due to a combination of factors, both a longstanding reluctance of Palestinians to collaborate with the Israeli government, and more recently a reluctance of Israel to give citizenship with the process becoming more difficult.
According to Ha'aretz, there have been various changes since the 1967 invasion. Initially there were some applications, mainly from those linked to the Israeli government, but after about 1975

applying for citizenship became taboo in Palestinian society, perceived as an acceptance of the occupation and as collaboration.

However after 2005 there was an increase in applications as increased oppression of Palestinians made Israeli nationality more desirable and indeed more necessary if you wanted to live free of some of the oppression of Palestinians.
But Israel has responded by making the process harder.

However, the Interior Ministry’s Population and Immigration Authority has made the process more difficult. Over the past 20 years, only 38 percent of the 16,573 applications have been approved. The main reason cited for denial was failure to prove that Jerusalem was their primary place of residence and employment. Additional reasons include the lack of Hebrew language skills, refusal to renounce Jordanian citizenship, criminal background or security impediments.


Just 5 Percent of E. Jerusalem Palestinians Have Received Israeli Citizenship Since 1967, Nir Hasson, Ha'aretz, May 29, 2022

